How can I reduce CPU usage when subscribing to multiple topics and monitor sensor reliability in ROS 2?
I am subscribing to 4 topics in ROS 2 (2 PointCloud2 topics and 2 Camera topics) with a QoS deadline specified. My goal is to raise an alert if the messages on any topic fail to meet the QoS deadline. To monitor this, I am using the deadline_callback from the subscription options, but I'm not processing any data in the callback (it is left empty, as shown below):
void HardwareChecker::setup_deadline_check(const TopicConfig& config) {
    rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions options;

    options.event_callbacks.deadline_callback = [this, topic_name = config.name](rclcpp::QOSDeadlineRequestedInfo& event) {
        this->deadlineMissedCallback(event, topic_name);
    };

    auto qos = rclcpp::QoS(10).deadline(rclcpp::Duration::from_seconds(config.deadline)).reliability(RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT);

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Setting up subscription for topic: %s with deadline: %f seconds and type: %s", config.name.c_str(),
                config.deadline, config.type.c_str());

    if (config.type == "sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2") {
        auto sub = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>(
            config.name, qos, [](const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr) {}, options);

        subscribers_pointcloud_.push_back(sub);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Subscription created for PointCloud2 on topic: %s", config.name.c_str());
    } else if (config.type == "sensor_msgs/msg/Image") {
        auto sub = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>(config.name, qos, [](const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::SharedPtr) {}, options);

        subscribers_image_.push_back(sub);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Subscription created for Image on topic: %s", config.name.c_str());
    }
}

Currently, the CPU usage is around 10% (as observed using htop), which seems high considering that the callback doesn't do any actual processing. Is there a way to reduce the CPU consumption associated with these subscriptions? Additionally, is there an alternative or more efficient way to monitor if the sensors are reliably publishing data within the specified QoS constraints?
I am running on Ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 Humble, rmw_cyclonedds
Any insights or suggestions for optimizing this would be appreciated.

The computational effort that your seeing reflected is from the communication layer, receiving, allocating, and deserializing the whole message before it provides you with the pointer that you're not using. The the message is deallocated because it has reference counted back to zero.
When I'm estimating I estimate that deserializing is about an order of magnitude more effort and time, and transporting the content is an order of magnitude longer still on a high performance system. So you really don't want to be triggering more than is necessary.
To that end subscribing just to check the rate is simple to do, but causes a very high load. A better approach would be to apply the qos to an existing subscribers which are already processing the topics.
Or add instrumentation to the publisher is also an option through diagnostics or topic statistics.
Excess subscribers can be especially problematic when you have lazy publishers that are optimized to not publish unless they have a subscriber attached. Thus you're adding load on the other end too. This is commonly implemented for high bandwidth producers like camera drivers because the effort will be nontrivial to send produce and send the messages.
